# Extract Data from body of http post request's response

Tags: angular, http

I have this http post request response.
[image]

I want to access the body of this response with out using .map. Any help!

Comment: just aside from the question, but, why you `don't want` to use map?

Comment: because if i use map then i can't get res.status!

Comment: Actually you can map everything, status included

Answer (score 0):

Simply you can make service like this.

```
getResponse() {
    return this.http.get(......).map(x => x.json());
  }
```

Then you can get this response from component like this.

```
this.customService.getResponse.subscribe(res => {
  console.log(res)
})
```

Comment: I don't want to use .map with get request? I want to simply reuturn the response from service to where it is called and then there i want to access the body of the response

Comment: if you remove the .map function then the response will be returned directly in the success callback of the subscribe (res)

Comment: If you don't want to use map inside service then just move `x=>x.json` to component. like `subscribe(res => { const body = res.json(); console.log(body)});`

Answer (score 0):

**Without using map :**

```
getResponse() {
    return this.http.get(......);
}

this.customService.getResponse.subscribe(res => {
  console.log(res.json())
})
```

> But , best practice is to use map

Comment: Yeah that's right..I have done this! But I am unable to extract auth token from body section of response! How can I do that?

Comment: do you have plunker for this ?

Comment: @ShoaibIqbal as others have stated, you parse your response with the .json() function. let bodyRes = x.json(); now you can grab your auth token from that bodyRes.auth_token

Comment: @LLai, exactly :)